# Reskit to parse foursquare menu API responses

Tags: json, restkit, foursquare

I'm using the following code to parse foursquare menu API Json responses.

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2"];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

RKObjectMapping *menuMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MenuSession class]];
[menuMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"name", @"name", @"description", @"description", nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:menuMapping forKeyPath:@"response.menu.menus.items"];
```

However, I got Error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

And here is the URL the RestKit request was using:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4a5ceb3af964a520d9bc1fe3/menu?client_secret=JBBJHVG3XZ1O4ZADAYHGMZLDNQWQ4HIJ2SG120MZ54GDCN1L&client_id=OSPAJRKHA4T53AGDZICIE0CL15DZCXHJWDY3J13R2CA4CTJ3

Any help will be much appreciated!

### Following is the response showing in Json parser

```
object      {2}

meta        {3}

response        {1}

          menu      {2}

                 provider       {4}

                 menus      {2}

                        count   :   1

                     items      [1]

                          0     {4}

                                 menuId :   myrf53yuauz9tlgtj6k4suf84

                                 name   :   Main Menu

                                 description    :   

                             entries        {2}
```

The full error messages are:
2013-10-16 22:50:04.842 CoffeeShop[807:a0b] response code: 200
2013-10-16 22:50:04.847 CoffeeShop[807:1403] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2013-10-16 22:50:04.847 CoffeeShop[807:1403] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:216 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''
2013-10-16 22:50:04.848 CoffeeShop[807:a0b] Error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

Comment: What version of RestKit? What is your destination object (what properties does it have)? What is the full error message? If you're just starting, use the latest version of RestKit.

Comment: Thanks Wain. I'm using the template from raywenderich tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial. The restkit can parse venue no problem but when I extend it to the menu API, the JSon response has more nested level and I'm not sure if my keypath is correct.

Comment: That's an old tutorial and old version of RestKit, you should upgrade.